# Bootstrap progress bar with dynamic progress value

Tags: django, django-templates, tags, django-tagging

I have a progress bar in a table similar to this:

[image: Example bar]

I can pass the value "2" for the percentage, but I cannot pass the value 2 to the `aria-valuenow` class that sets how fill is shown the progress bar. How could I pass the dynamic value to `aria-valuenow` so the progress bar shows the right filling?

I tried `{{value.3}}`,`"{{value.3}}"`, the same with only one `{}` and with/without `% %`. I really run out of imagination.

```
{% for key,value in ctxt.items %}
  <tr><td>{{value.0}}</td><td>{{value.1}}</td><td>
    {% if value.3 %}
    <div class="progress align-content-center position-relative" style="height: 25px;">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow= "{% value.3 %}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      <small class="justify-content-center  d-flex position-absolute w-100">{{value.3}}%</small>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

*Another battle is to put the "2%" vertically centered and not in the top with the `position-absolute` commands. If you know this, really appreciated too!

Comment: Try this: **aria-valuenow="{{ value.3 }}"**.

Comment: I think when we pass as html/css element/source, we have to give space between braces. and no spaces when it is passed as template variable.

Comment: @azzam I tried but still no result :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the value of the bar is not defined by aria-valuenow but by the width. So the bar should work as follows:

```
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: {{ value.3 }}%;" aria-valuenow= "{{ value.3 }}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
```